# Get last 10 records in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Please can any one help me in writing a query.

I want to get the last inserted 10 records from a table.

Comment: Do you have an identity column or a column with the date the resord was inserted? Also show us your schema.

Answer (score 3):

It would be something like

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyID DESC
```

MyID should be the primary key

Comment: Why Primary key? If I insert into a primary key column the value is this order K,A,B,R,G. Your solution wouldn't work.

Comment: it's not correct. first, MyID may be e.g. varchar, then order by will not work properly, second, even if MyID is integer, it can be declared not as IDENTITY 1,1.

Comment: Or to rephrase what Ash is saying, you shouldn't conflate "primary key" and "identity/autonumber column" the two are *distinct* concepts, and shouldn't be thought of as the same thing.

Comment: Given the lack of specifics, I chose the most likely answer

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your table has a primary key which is an identity column:

Select top 10 * 
from mytable
order by mytable.id desc

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a field in your table declared like this:

```
date_putin datetime not null default getdate()
```

and unless this field can never be written to by a client, you can't. Because there's no row order in a table.

But if you do have this field, and no client can ever write to it, then

```
select top (10) * from t order by date_putin desc;
```